# IDE не понимают мультистроковые php переменные содержащие html код

Tags: php, html, ide

Вот уже сколько мучаюсь с этим, может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался?

```
$TEMPLATE['frame_list'] = <<<END
  <div class="header">
    <div>Текст</div>
    <span>Текст</span>
    <span>Текст</span>
  </div>
END;
```

Вот этот html код не распознается или криво распознается различными IDE'шками.

Использую php storm и sublime text, второй вообще никак не распознает html в мультистроковых переменных, php storm жутко коряво распознает. (php storm'у отписывал в багтрекер, но думаю что и через 100 лет ничего не изменится http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12815 )

Есть ли какой-нибудь плагин или еще какое либо решения данной проблемы?

Comment: по моему лучшее решение вашей проблемы - не писать такой код

Comment: На самом деле на этом завязана CMS, и это довольно таки удобно, было бы круто если кто то написал плагин или посоветовал куда начать копать в таком случае...

Comment: Это ужеасно, используйте лучше шаблоны. Хватит как в каменном веке мешать код и представление

Comment: это и есть файлы шаблонов, в одном шаблоне может быть множество таких блоков: $TEMPLATE хранить в себе все блоки, а дальше движок уже использует их по своему усмотрению парсятся макросы и тд и тп
ЗЫ давайте не будем уходить от темы =)